# Seam on middle of Bevel with modifier

Tags: uv, modifiers, bevel

When applying bevels (or, in my case, exporting meshes with Bevel modifiers), results are best with an *even* amount of bevels (2, 4, 6..). However, the seams are always transferred to the **outer** edges of the bevel, while (with an even amount of bevel) the result would be so much better if Blender could apply it do the **inner** edges of the bevel.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Before:
[image: Before]

Current Result:
[image: Current]

Desired Result:
[image: Desired]

Comment: It seems that it was asked before here https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/Xvbbbc/.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mark seam on middle edges of beveled edges created by bevel modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250839/mark-seam-on-middle-edges-of-beveled-edges-created-by-bevel-modifier)

Comment: @Quellenform Thanks for your input :) 

No, it doesn't really answer the question. I'm looking for a way to keep the right seems when applying new bevels (from a modifier or otherwise). You can of course re-generate them (which is what your link is about), but that's not the point.