# Mark seam on middle edges of beveled edges created by bevel modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel

[image]

Just as you can see on the screenshot, I would like to mark the middle edge of beveled edges created by bevel modifier when applied. By default bevel modifier will just mark outer edges. I would like it to be the middle edges

Answer (score 3):

You can do it manually with *three* clicks.

<kbd>Alt + Left Mouse</kbd> to select one edge.
And then *Select > Similar > Face Angles*

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it only works on simple geometry, I would like to know automatic way

Answer (score 0):

Not auto, but less pain. You can save mark seam as new vertex group(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>), then when you bevel(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or apply modifier) with even amount i.e:2-4-6, you can come back and select vertex group > remove seam(<kbd>U</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - until middle edges are selected. Mark seam again(<kbd>U</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>).